# E4 RCP How to set selection of ToolBarItem that contains Radio Buttons

Tags: drop-down-menu, radio-button, toolbar, rcp, e4

In Eclipse E4 (Luna), using the application model to create parts, handlers, commands, handled menu items etc, (these are not created programatically). I have a toolbar.  This contains a sub-Menu item called "Filter" that contains another sub-menu of two filters.  The two filters are two Handled Menu Items which are set up as "Radio" Buttons.

When I select the appropriate in the UI of my running app from the selection, the Radio button switches just fine to the selected Item.  However I would like this selection to update (deselecting one Radio button and selecting the appropriate radio button of the handled menu item) when my ViewPart changes through other UI selection.   Currently my ViewPart updates, but the Radio buttons are on the same previous selection through the UI.

Is there a way in which I get access both Handled Menu Item's IDs and set the selection (one to false, the other to true) when the viewer is updated.

Image of design is attached below: [image: Toolbar item containing handled menu items]

Hierarchy of the application model is as follows:
[image: hierarchy]

Thanks in advance,

Marv

Comment: Can you show the code for constuction the menu? Edit your question.

Comment: The Handled Menu items are created within the application model in e4 and assigned unique IDs, so they are not  created programatically.

Comment: How are you getting a Menu as a child of 'Direct Tool Item'? The e4xmi editor does not allow this.

Comment: I simply clicked on the "Menu" Check box in the Direct Tool Items settings. And a Menu appears in the hierarchy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by starting with MPart PartID and drilling down to the HandledMenuItems on which I wanted to set the Radio Button selections, then setting the selection property for each individual HandledMenuItem.

This can probably be refactored to be more concise, but I've left the code with each step to have the solution easier to read.

BTW, in every instance / combination of the EModelService methods, the list returned a size of 0.  So I'm not certain if that will work for what I'm trying to achieve.  The following does work, although I'm not certain it is the most efficient means.

I hope this helps others.

```
    // Get view part
    MPart viewPart = _partService.findPart("part_id");

    //  get list of all menu items from the Part
    List<MMenu> viewPartMenu = viewPart.getMenus();

    // Get list of ViewMenus from viewPartMenu there is only one View Menu so it will be index 0
    MMenu viewMenu = viewPartMenu .get(0);

    // Get list of MMenuElements from the viewMenu - the children in the view menu
    List<MMenuElement> viewMenuElements = viewMenu.getChildren();

    // This gets me to the 2 HandledMenuItems 
    // Upper Most HandledMenuItem Radio Button is at viewMenuElements index 0.  This is cast to MHandledMenuItem
    MHandledMenuItem upperHandledMenuItem = (MHandledMenuItem) viewMenuElements.get(0);

    // Set Selection 
    upperHandledMenuItem.setSelected(false);

    // Lower Most HandledMenuItem Radio Button is at viewMenuElements index 1.  This is cast to MHandledMenuItem
    MHandledMenuItem lowerHandledMenuItem = (MHandledMenuItem) viewMenuElements.get(1);

    // Set selection 
    lowerHandledMenuItem.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the model service to find menu items. Use something like:

```java
@Inject
EModelService modelService;

@Inject
MApplication app;


List<MMenuItem> items = modelService.findElements(app, "menu item id", MMenuItem.class, Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_MAIN_MENU);
```

Once you have the `MMenuItem` you can call the `setSelected(boolean)` method to change the selection.

To find a menu item which is in a Part menu use:

```java
modelService.findElements(app, "menu item id", MMenuItem.class, Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_PART);
```

(IN_PART argument instead of IN_MAIN_MENU).

You could also specify the MPart rather than the Application as the first argument to `findElements` which may speed up the search.

For menus as a child of a Tool Bar Item it appears that the model services cannot find these directly. However you can find the Tool Bar Item and look at the menu yourself:

```java
List<MToolItem> items = modelService.findElements(app, "tool bar item id", MToolItem.class, Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_PART);

MToolItem item = items.get(0);

MMenu menu = item.getMenu();

List<MMenuElement> children = menu.getChildren();

... search menu elements
```

Comment: Hi greg-449, Thanks for the quick reply.   I've added that code, but I continue to return a list of Items with the size of 0.  I've tried a few menu item ids to see if that would change any... unfortunately still returns size of 0.  Any suggestions? FYI, I'm creating these Handled Menu Items using e4's application model (not programatically). . Also the menu items are in a toolbar within a Part View as a sub-menus in a a drop down menu item.

Comment: Hi greg-449, The Handled Menu Items are in a Part.   
Part
    ToolBar
        Direct Tool Item, 
            Menu
                Menu
                    Handled Menu item1 (Radio)
                    Handled Menu Item2 (Radio)

Comment: Show us the design so we are clear where the menu items are. You will need to change the findElements call for menu items which are not in the main menu.

Comment: Added findElements for a menu in a part to answer

Comment: Hi greg-449, I've edited the question to include an image of the design.  A part with a toolbar item, containing a direct tool item, that contains a menu containing a menu (filter), which contains 2 handled menu items (show all & show single).  I've tried all other findElements calls for that method and still it is returning 0.  Sorry if this was not as specific as needed to solve this, but any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Thank you... I've tried, List<MMenuItem> items = modelService.findElements(application, "my_handled_menu_item_id", MMenuItem.class, Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_PART); is still returning a value of 0 for list.size()...  I wonder if this is possible... Odd thing is that when I call the MMenuItem item from the execute(MMenuItem item) and have item.setSelection(true), it selected the correct radio button, but the other menu item doe not deselect it's radio button...

Comment: Hi, Thank you again for the help.  Still not returning everything tried every combination... List<MToolItem> items = modelService.findElements(app, "tool bar item id", MToolItem.class, Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_PART);  Even tried putting a generic in the List as in:    List<?> items = modelService.findElements(app, "tool bar item id", null, Collections.emptyList(), EModelService.IN_PART);    In every instance the List that is returned is still size() of zero.  I'll keep looking for a solution but think ModelService might not be able to get the elements I need by their IDs..

Comment: Any help on this one... everything returns an empty list.  Any further help would be appreciated.